# Converting string with minutes over 60 into time datatype causes an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Declare @Data Table (Working_Hours nvarchar(10));  datatable

insert into @Data (working_hours) select '0:10';   insertion values
insert into @Data (working_hours) select '1:90';
insert into @Data (working_hours) select '0:10';
insert into @Data (working_hours) select '0:10';

--select working_hours from @Data;  *this state work* 

--select @data as lion ; this state also work

select 
    convert(int, (datepart(hour, CONVERT(time, q1.working_hours)) * 60) +
                  DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(time, q1.working_hours))) as lion 
from @Data q1;
```

results in a conversion error - I want to convert min from `nvarchar` and then convert into int to calculate sum in sap report

How can denominate the work through way..

Comment: Is that supposed to be hours and minutes? What is 1 hour and 90 minutes?

Comment: Why isn't that 2 hours and 30 minutes?

Comment: its just a mistake its not an actual code....sorry for late but m out of this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's just hours and minutes with problems with the data (90 minutes), you can do this without using time -datatype which of course doesn't allow that kind of time:

```
select 
  convert(int, left(working_hours, charindex(':', working_hours)-1)) * 60 + 
  convert(int, substring(working_hours, charindex(':', working_hours)+1,10))
from
  @data
```

Comment: Extend your solution for minutes over 60, see https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/373885. Use substring to end of string, not just 2 chars

Comment: Well if there's even bigger numbers, the substring must be changed accordingly.

Comment: Or just use `LEN(working_hours) - charindex(':', working_hours))` No need for hardcoded value. But this is **overengineering** ;)

Comment: man there is an error of length of both left and substring How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Will work with SQL Server 2012+**

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/373874)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT  [working_hours] =  REPLACE(q1.working_hours, ':', '.')
  FROM @Data q1
)
SELECT
  [lion] = PARSENAME(working_hours, 2) * 60 + PARSENAME(working_hours, 1)
FROM cte
```

One way or another you need to get chunks of data. So one fancy way to do it is to use `PARSENAME`